# Patching macvim remote editing, file netrw.vim

Tags: macos, vim, scp, macvim, netrw

So there's a problem with macvim when doing remote editing through 
:e scp://path/to/file
Every time I try to save :w, macvim complains E382: Cannot write, 'buftype' option is set. 
The quick fix to solving this is to do :set buftype:""
However, there are patches out there to solve the issue. So I downloaded a patch file to fix this problem. The problem is located in the netrw.vim file. When I try to patch the file netrw.vim through patch -p1 < file.patch, it gives me an error that says 
patch: **** Can't rename file netrw.vim to netrw.vim.orig : Permission denied

I tried chmod for netrw.vim, but it doesn't let me.
Any help is appreciated!
p.s. I'm running on OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 0):

I just tried mvim scp://hostname/, picked a file, edited and changed it, and saved it.  It worked.
I then tried mvim scp://hostname/somefile, edited and changed it, and saved it.  It worked.
So, I suggest that you upgrade: you can find netrw v154b on http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW .
btw, the mvim I used is v7.4.258 .

Answer (score 0):

if you opened a remote directory and selected a file to edit you need create the tmp file in you local and set this command `:set by=acwrite` or `:set buftype=acwrite` and finally save your changes `:w`.